# Crontab never running while in /etc/cron.d

Tags: debian, cron

Here's what I did on Debian Jessie:

- install cron via `apt-get install cron`
- put a `backup_crontab` file in `/etc/cron.d/`

However the task is never running.

Here are some outputs:

```
/# crontab -l
no crontab for root

/# cd /etc/cron.d && ls
backup_crontab

/etc/cron.d# cat backup_crontab
0,15,30,45 * * * * /backup.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Is there something to do to activate a particular crontab, or to activate the cron "service" in itself?

Comment: What if it's running and failing with an error you don't get to see because you're redirecting all output to /dev/null? :)

Comment: @tink is it possible to append the output to the end of a file instead?

Comment: sure is;   0,15,30,45 * * * * /backup.sh >>/tmp/testing_cron.out  2>&1

Comment: @Jivan, just a small note: `ls /etc/cron.d` is equivalent to `cd /etc/cron.d && ls` in terms of output. The only difference is the working directory won't change.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Files in `/etc/cron.d` need to also list the *user* that the job is to be run under.

i.e.

```
0,15,30,45 * * * * root /backup.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

You should also ensure the permissions and owner:group are set correctly (`-rw-r--r--` and owned by `root:root`)

Comment: Thanks. But still nothing. `/etc/init.d/cron status` is `running` and `crontab -l` still replies `no crontab for root`

Comment: `crontab -l` reports on cron entries in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/` - ie the _per user_ crontabs.  `/etc/cron.d` files are system crontabs and not reported by `crontab -l`.

Comment: @StephenHarris didn't know that, okay so I'll wait an hour or so to check if the script has been executed

Comment: @clk thanks for pointing that - yes the script is executable

Comment: Actually I mentioned that it was not working but I just realized that it is after having add `root` in the file - just `crontab -l` didn't mention it, as you explained why - thanks for your help

Comment: it seems that also the filename has a role. In my case I had added to `etc/cron.d` a file with a dot in the middle of the name and the job was never executed until I renamed it

Comment: same problem here, dashes "-" in filename, changing them to underscores "_" solved the problem, jobs ran immediately.

Comment: I also had a dash... what the.... why?! Anyway, thanks @Rob

Comment: More details here about filename formats etc... https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/417327/28653

Comment: THANK YOU @Rob ... and Tony for the link....wow.

Comment: In addition, the user that is specified in the 6th column of a cron.d file needs to be valid, i.e. have `getent passwd` and `getent shadow` entries. Otherwise, cron may reload the cron.d file nicely, yet always skip the actual invocation altogether, without any notice in the logs. I noticed this thanks to a comment elsewhere on SE, so I'm passing it along.

Comment: In my case it was the file permissions. Changing from 0664 to 0644 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 26):

Another thing I've observed is that the file in `/etc/cron.d` cannot have an extension. In my particular case, I had a symbolic link:

```
# my-job.crontab
* * * * * root echo "my job is running!" >> /tmp/my-job.log

$: ln -sf /home/me/my-job.crontab /etc/cron.d/
# This did not work -> job would not run

$: ln -sf /home/me/my-job.crontab /etc/cron.d/my-job
# This did work -> job ran fine
```

File name restriction are documented at run-part man page: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/run-parts.8.html, one can pass 
an --regex option to override the file format.

The default cron behavior however stayed without extensions, see comments under: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debianutils/+bug/38022

Comment: This is correct on Ubuntu (maybe on all Debian-derived distros). On Amazon Linux (and maybe on all Redhat-derived distros), you can have a dot in the file name. Thank you Unix.SE.

Comment: I just checked a pure Debian, and dots do not work there either. Dashes do work (unlike what a comment above says).

Answer (score 23):

I think you probably just missing a necessary blank line from the end of your cron file. I had the same issue, but after checking everything listed here (user permissions, filename, cron version etc.), I realized that I did not have line break after the last entry in my `/etc/cron.d/own_cron` and that causes the entire file being ignored.

Answer (score 5):

For Cron from *bian distros (like Raspbian) you need to enable the `-l` parameter of the Cron daemon. That is advisable to do using `/etc/default/cron` config file, enabling the `EXTRA_OPTS`.

Comment: This was downvoted, but it is correct in some cases, although not explained. On Debian-based distros the `-l` option to the cron daemon authorizes an extended set of file names in the `/etc/cron.d` directory, so if the file is being silently ignored because there is a dot in it, then either "adding -l" or "removing dot" will correct the problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you're the only user on this computer, you might want to use just `crontab -e`. You'll be prompted to select an editor the first time you run the command. Then you can add this to it:

```
0,15,30,45 * * * * /backup.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

If you change to a normal user account, you'll need to use `sudo crontab -e` to configure the scripts you want scheduled to run as `root`.

`crontab -l` only displays the current crontab, once you set one up using `crontab -e`. If you have a cron file in `/etc/cron.d`/, it will not be displayed with `crontab -l`.

You will also need to verify that your script is executable with: `chmod +x /backup.sh`.

Comment: thanks - in this case the crontab is set in the context of a `Dockerfile` so I can't really do `crontab -e` - but it's a useful information anyway

Answer (score 3):

1. First of all, check the `/var/log/syslog` file for **cron.d errors**,

   `sudo grep "cron.d" /var/log/syslog |grep -i error`

   could be useful to find **errors** like bad usernames or bad syntax
2. If you don't have any, check for all `cron.d` entries into the same file with

   `sudo grep "cron.d" /var/log/syslog`

Comment: on RHEL7, it can be found on log file /var/log/cron

Answer (score 2):

Check your version of `cron`.

It seems that if you are using Dillon's crond, you don't need the user in a `/etc/cron.d` entry.

I figured this out after nearly pulling out my remaining hair.

I have a handful of entries that have been dropped in `/etc/cron.d` by various installs.  After some investigation, I found one of them was working.  It didn't have the user.  So I took the user out of the others.  And they began working.

Comment: It would help if you included some info to work out if you are using Dillon's crond, thanks!

Comment: Debian has always used Vixie. See https://wiki.debian.org/cron#cron-1