# What is the difference between cron.d (as in /etc/cron.d/) and crontab?

Tags: debian, cron

What is the main difference between the directory cron.d (as in `/etc/cron.d/`) and `crontab`?

As far as I understand, one could create a file like `/etc/cron.d/my_non_crontab_cronjobs` and put whatever one wants inside it, just as one would put them in `crontab` via `crontab -e`.

So what is the main difference between the two?

Comment: location in the system, and format.

Comment: Format? From 2 examples I've seen it also has the 5 time units syntax, or I'm confusing it with `crontab`.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The differences are documented in detail in [the `cron(8)` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/cron/cron.8) in Debian. The main difference is that `/etc/cron.d` is populated with separate files, whereas `crontab` manages one file per user; it’s thus easier to manage the contents of `/etc/cron.d` using scripts (for automated installation and updates), and easier to manage `crontab` using an editor (for end users really).

Other important differences are that not all distributions support `/etc/cron.d`, and that the files in `/etc/cron.d` have to meet a certain number of requirements (beyond being valid cron jobs): they must be owned by root, and must conform to `run-parts`’ naming conventions (*no dots*, only letters, digits, underscores, and hyphens).

If you’re considering using `/etc/cron.d`, it’s usually worth considering one of `/etc/cron.hourly`, `/etc/cron.daily`, `/etc/cron.weekly`, or `/etc/cron.monthly` instead.

Comment: And for a real-world example, the items in `cron.d` are typically added via package installation, whereas the various `crontab` files are full of things created by a corresponding user.  IE, the `certbot` or `letsencrypt` package puts an entry in `cron.d` - before the package was available, the sysadmin (root) would add an entry in the root user's `crontab` pointing to a shell script/etc. to keep the certificates up to date.

Comment: Thanks Stephen! Why do you recommend using hourly/weekly/monthly cron directories? And BTW, why is the man page there called cron(8) what is the 8 for (the man page for crontab named crontab(1)).

Comment: @Arcticooling, see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/what-do-the-numbers-in-a-man-page-mean) for an explanation of the `(8)`

Comment: The hourly etc. directories make it simpler to add jobs (no need to figure out the exact syntax), and more importantly, allow the system to vary the real execution time depending on circumstances; this is particularly useful on systems which aren’t always on, with `anacron`.

Comment: The downside of the `hourly|daily|weekly|monthly` directories is that (AFAICT), they always run as root, and don't directly support running with lesser privilege.

Comment: Dear @StephenKitt I was sad to discover that `bash.bashrc` variables aren't expanded on `/etc/cron.d/` files. Also, I seem not to be able to source files there.

Comment: @Arcticooling what do you mean by “source files there”? Re `bashrc`, that’s been answered with one of your other questions.

Comment: Thanks. I have a similar question and appreciate your help https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/458713/how-are-files-under-etc-cron-d-used

Answer (score 10):

I would say the main difference is the obvious one: `/etc/crontab` and `/etc/cron.d` are not modifiable by regular users, while the per-user crontabs in `/var/spool/cron` that the `crontab` tool edits, are. (Subject to `cron.allow` and `cron.deny`, of course.) Of course on a system where you are the administrator, you could use either. On a shared system, the regular users can only use one.

Related to this is the extra field in the system-wide files, the username under which the job runs.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the differences pointed out in the other answers, one major disadvantage of `crontab -e` from the usage point of view is how easily you can accidentally delete all your crons with one simple mistake.

Command `crontab -r` removes, without warning or prompt, all the cron entries you would have in your crontab. And guess what, the letter `e` used for editing is just next to `r` on the keyboard!

Hence `/etc/cron.d/` >> `crontab -e`