# How are files under /etc/cron.d used?

Tags: cron

How are files under /etc/cron.d used?

From  https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

> **cron reads the files in /etc/cron.d/ directory.** Usually system daemon
>   such as sa-update or sysstat places their cronjob here. As a root user
>   or superuser you can use following directories to configure cron jobs.
>   **You can directly drop your scripts here**. **The run-parts command run
>   scripts or programs in a directory via /etc/crontab file**:
>
> /etc/cron.d/  **Put all scripts here and call them from /etc/crontab
>   file.**

On Lubuntu 18.04, the files under /etc/cron.d seem to be crontab files not shell scripts (which was mentioned in the above link):

```
$ cat /etc/cron.d/anacron 
# /etc/cron.d/anacron: crontab entries for the anacron package

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

30 7    * * *   root    [ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi
```

My /etc/crontab file never refers to files under/etc/cron.d, contrary to what the link says:

```
$ cat /etc/crontab 
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

Could you explain how the files under /etc/cron.d are used? Thanks.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In Debian derivatives, including Lubuntu, the files in `/etc/cron.d` are effectively `/etc/crontab` snippets, with the same format. Quoting [the `cron` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/cron/cron.8):

> Additionally, in Debian, `cron` reads the files in the `/etc/cron.d` directory. `cron` treats the files in `/etc/cron.d` as in the same way as the `/etc/crontab` file (they follow the special format of that file, i.e. they include the user field). However, they are independent of `/etc/crontab`: they do not, for example, inherit environment variable settings from it. This change is specific to Debian see the note under DEBIAN SPECIFIC below.
>
> Like `/etc/crontab`, the files in the `/etc/cron.d` directory are monitored for changes. In general, the system administrator should not use `/etc/cron.d/`, but use the standard system crontab `/etc/crontab`.

The Debian-specific section hints at the reason system administrators shouldn’t use `/etc/cron.d`:

> Support for `/etc/cron.d` (drop-in dir for package crontabs)

It’s designed to allow packages to install crontab snippets without having to modify `/etc/crontab`.

Comment: Thanks. Are the files in /etc/cron.d and  /etc/crontab independent of each other, and read by crond independently and separately? Or does /etc/crontab ever include the files in /etc/cron.d?

Comment: “However, they are independent of `/etc/crontab`”, as quoted above. To be absolutely clear, `/etc/crontab` doesn’t include files from `/etc/cron.d` by default. (As an administrator, you could place commands in `/etc/cron.d` and use them in `/etc/crontab`, but that would be thoroughly confusing.)

Comment: Thanks. "In general, the system administrator should not use /etc/cron.d/, but use the standard system crontab /etc/crontab."  When should a sysadmin use `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` or `/etc/crontab`?

Comment: I only ever use `/var/spool/cron` for user-specific jobs. Any system job should go in `/etc/crontab` or `/etc/cron.{hourly,daily,weekly,monthly}` IMO.

Comment: Thanks. (1) What do "system job" and "user specific job" mean?   (2) Is `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` for system jobs? root-specific jobs are system jobs, I guess?  (3) `anacron` by default only runs `/etc/cron.{hourly,daily,weekly,monthly}/*`, so is `anacron` used only for system jobs not for user-specific jobs?

Comment: As far as I’m concerned, as I said above `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` is for user-specific jobs. If an admin chooses to use root as a user account, then it would make sense for root’s jobs (the user’s, *not* the system’s) to go in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root`. But since root shouldn’t be used as a user account, I tend to think that `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` shouldn’t be used either.

Comment: Please don’t edit comments so radically when they ask questions :-(.

Comment: A system job is a job which applies to the whole system. A user-specific job is a job run on behalf of a specific user; typically, tasks which the user would do manually while logged in, but which he/she wishes to perform periodically and automatically — *e.g.* backups of specific files, or refreshes of remote development repositories, or mail processing, or mirroring web sites...

Comment: anacron only deals with system jobs, yes.

Comment: Thanks. My apology.  `sudo crontab -e` will create `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root`, so I thought that that file can be created so must be used for some purpose.

Comment: `crontab -e` run as any user will create a user-specific crontab for that user; root is no different. But the way root should be used means there’s not much point in having a root-specific crontab in `/var/spool/cron`.

Comment: People might miss, that "[the file names must conform to the filename requirements of run-parts](https://www.google.com/search?q="the+file+names+must+conform+to+the+filename+requirements+of+run-parts")" (see Debian's `man cron`).  So **filenames in `/etc/cron.d/` which match the shell glob `*[!A-Za-z0-9_-]*` are ignored!**  Hence things like `*.dpkg-dist` or `vi`-backups `*~` do no harm, but if you accidentally create `/etc/cron.d/very_important.crontab`, this will get ignored due to the `.` in it!

Comment: Another thing to take note of is files in `/etc/cron.d` ***MUST*** include the `user` field or they simply _will not run_ - with nothing being logged to indicate what the problem is.

Comment: My /etc/cron.d/company does not seem to run
*/3 * * * * www-data /home/company/path/to/script
Running su - www-data -c /home/company/path/to/script is working

Comment: Does "are monitored for changes" mean I don't have to restart anything after a modification to cron.d files?

Comment: @racitup that‘s right, nothing needs to be restarted or reloaded.